# Typescript: Usage of Map<> with strictNullChecks

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, strictnullchecks

Given the following simple class:

```
class Observer {
        private subscribers: Map<string, Array<((data: any) => void)>> = new Map();     

        public subscribe(event: string, callback: (data: any) => void) {
            if (!this.subscribers.has(event)) {
                this.subscribers.set(event, []);
            }

            this.subscribers.get(event).push(callback); //tsc says: Object is possibly 'undefined'
        }
    }
```

Furthermore, in tsconfig.json, the flags `strictNullChecks` and `strict` are enabled.

Although `subscribers` is checked for a key of the current event, the typescript compiler complains with the error message shown above (`this.subscribers.get(event)` is possibly undefined).

If I'm not completely wrong, `this.subscribers.get(event)` can never be `undefined` in this case.

How can I get rid of that message?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Typing of `Map` explicitly states that `get` can result in `undefined`:

```
interface Map<K, V> {
    ...
    get(key: K): V | undefined;
    ...
}
```

That's why you're getting error with strictNullChecks enabled.

You can use [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) to inform the compiler that you're sure that it actually has value:

```
this.subscribers.get(event)!.push(callback);
```

**Another option** (the better one in my opinion) is to refactor your code in following way:

```
public subscribe(event: string, callback: (data: any) => void) {
    let callbacks = this.subscribers.get(event);
    if (!callbacks) {
        callbacks = []
        this.subscribers.set(event, callbacks);
    }

    callbacks.push(callback);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not writing a new interface/class that would not tolerate undefined values?

```js
interface StrictMap<K, V> {
    ...
    get(key: K): V /* `| undefined` -> main diff. with `Map` native interface: The values can't be undefined */;
    ...
}
```

PS : In fact, I was searching for such an interface/class when I found this SO post ;)